# Vue v-for list not updating with v-set

Tags: javascript, vue.js

my simple application fetches data from an API and renders the array on the page using a v-for list.

The array looks like this

```
posts : [{id : 1, likes: 2}, {id: 2, likes: 3} ...]
```

The loop looks like this

```
<div v-for="post in posts" :key = "post.id">
    <p>{{ post.title}} </p>
    <button @click="like(post.id)">Like</button>
</div>
```

I am trying to update the like count on a button click, I'm using the following command but even though the like count is updating the rendered like count is not updating.

```
like(id) {
    // post request sent to bank end
    this.$set(posts[id], 'likes', newLikes)
    console.log(this.posts)
}
```

Even though the likes count is updated, the new value is not shown on the page updating the v-for render, what is the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think `this.$set(posts[id], ..)` is a typo, right? You forgot `this.`

Comment: You should fetch your posts in `mounted` hook and add it to your component `data`. Then it is reactive and should trigger rerender on update.

Comment: Hi yes i am doing it like that, i'm fetching and updating the data on `mounted` hook, my data is updated fine on button click, but it's not rendering on the frontend, I can't seem a way to fix it, any idea?

Comment: I just edited my answer. You are trying to use `post.id` as array index for `posts`. Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is much easier! I didnt see it before:
You are using `post.id` as array's index.

What you have to do is `v-for="(post, idx) in posts"` and `@click="like(idx)"`

***NOTICE**: The answer below was before I fully understood the problem and has nothing todo with OPs problem, but is still useful.*

What I always do in `v-for` with array of objects is passing `onClick` (or any event handler) the whole object. It is passed by reference, so its exactly the object from the array and not a copy. Makes code much smaller and more readable.

I dont know, if its the best performance solution if you have thousands of components, though.

```
<template>
  <div v-for="post in posts" :key="`${_uid}_${post.id}`">
    <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
    <button @click="onClickLike(post)">Like</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      posts: []
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
    this.posts = await fetch('https://api.web.site/v2/posts')
  },
  methods: {
    onClickLike (post) {
      post.like++
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Otherwise you'd first have to `.filter` the post from the array in the `@click` handler by `post.id` and then update it.

Comment: Hi yes fixing the key and the `like(id)` it with the `like(index)` fixed the issue, thank you very much.

I don't understand what broke the first code

Comment: Very easy: `post.id` is a number that _you_ defined for the post, while `idx` is the array index. If you re-order the posts, then the `post.id`s stay the same but the `idx`s change, because the post is in another position in the array.